# How could we keep a modifiable list on my chat group?

Tags: telegram

In my [Telegram](https://desktop.telegram.org/)'s chat group we need to create a **list** (say a list of price for drinks) :

```
Coca-Cola       1 €
Vodka           3 €
Orange juice    0,50 €
Apple juice     0,30 €
```

But, as time passes, these prices will change, so we will need to make **changes** in that list, and Telegram does only allow to modify messages in the last 48 hours.

What is the best workaround to **keep a modifiable list** that could be used in a Telegram's chat group?

Maybe there is no better way that creating a simple web page on a free site like Google, and link it into the chat? Maybe copy-pasting that list each 48 hours in the chat? Maybe Telegram web site offers some service that could be used for this, like the personal data of a user?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on-topic on Superuser. Also, we are not a scripting service nor say what is the best way to accomplish that task.

Comment: This is indeed not on-topic, given that Telegram, like WhatsApp is originally a web app, and fits better at webapps.stackexchange

Comment: That said, I think the easiest way is to use an excelsheet and simply upload it to the group. Each time you need to change it, access Files, delete the previous and upload a new version.

Comment: No problem to transfer it to WebApps, then. I have flagged it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 solution to this problem:

1) copy and paste the old list into a new list and delete the old one (you can delete for more then 48 hours)

2) use a second document outside of Telegram e.g. Google Spreadsheets and just post a link to the document in the description of your group

Comment: Well, your first workaround would place the list/message in a different (chronological) position of the chat, but you can always use the search tool to find it.